# Numpy performance of loading array then transposing vs. loading transposed array

Tags: python, numpy

**Edit for clarity: this is *not* a question about loading times, rather a question about any differences in processing *after the arrays have already been loaded*.**

I have discovered something odd while testing my code and would like to know what causes a significant different in performance when operating on identical matrices that were simply loaded differently.

In short, I have saved to text files relatively large binary matrices. Due to unrelated reasons I ended up testing my code using two methods: one where the matrices transposed, saved, then loaded, while the other method saves the matrices, loads them, then transposes them.

The resulting matrices are identical to each other, yet I see significant difference in the performance of my code. Below is an example demonstrating this, though the test function is only a representation of the various operations I perform in my actual code (some slicing, bitwise operations, sums).

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

M = np.loadtxt("m.txt").astype(np.uint8).transpose()
P = np.loadtxt("p.txt").astype(np.uint8).transpose()
L = np.loadtxt("l.txt").astype(np.uint8).transpose()

MT = np.loadtxt("mt.txt").astype(np.uint8)
PT = np.loadtxt("pt.txt").astype(np.uint8)
LT = np.loadtxt("lt.txt").astype(np.uint8)

assert (M == MT).all()
assert (P == PT).all()
assert (L == LT).all()

def test(M, P, L, n=100):
    np.random.seed(1138)
    count = 0
    for i in tqdm(range(n)):
        for j in range(M.shape[1]):
            temp = np.bitwise_xor(M[:,j].reshape(-1, 1), L[:, np.random.choice(L.shape[1], P.shape[1])])
            temp = np.bitwise_xor(P, temp)
            count += temp.sum()
    return count

assert test(M, P, L) == test(MT, PT, LT)
```

which produces the following output:

```
M.shape: (10000, 2)
P.shape: (10000, 1024)
L.shape: (10000, 256)
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:02<00:00, 38.22it/s]
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:11<00:00,  8.49it/s]
```

As you can see, the first method takes 2 seconds while the second method takes 11 seconds. What could be the reason for this difference?

Comment: `loadtxt` reads lines of text and parses them.  So we can expect differences between loading a few long lines versus many shorter ones.  `numpy` transpose is fast array operation, taking microseconds to do.

Comment: This is not a question about the load times themselves; my question is why, after the matrices are already loaded, the `test` function performs differently.

Comment: It might be that transpose() doesn't actually restructure the data in memory, it just notes that the data should be interpreted differently, which is why it's usually a pretty instant operation. Essentially, the work of actually doing the transpose is being amortized into your for loop. You could retry the test but add a copy() after the transpose() and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Your subject line highlights two different load sequences.  I'm saying that the `loadtxt` for the different files probably accounts for the time difference.

Comment: @Colin this appears to be the answer. Adding `copy()` after the `transpose()` results in the same runtimes. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, transpose returns a *view* with the stride being swapped. Copying the view cause a new contiguous array to be created. You can also use [np.ascontiguousarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html). Strides matter for performance and also impact the behaviour of in-place functions.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you get the view when transposed(which means same data but viewed differently). When looping over j, the transposed array will have more cache misses as it has to load and flush the data number of times than the non transposed array. you could change  ```M = np.loadtxt("m.txt").transpose().astype(np.uint8)``` line and you will get the same performance on both arrays. When using ```np.astype()``` it creates a new copy of data which will be contiguous and exactly has same memory patterns as MT